# How to upgrade Google Analytics for Unity plugin from V3 to V4?

Tags: google-analytics, unity-game-engine, google-analytics-sdk

My game is using Google Analytics for Unity for V3. Now I need to upgrade to V4. Is there any easy/safe way to do this? I'm not good at programming.

Thanks.

Comment: there is only one way of doing it - remove V3 from the project (at this point a ton of errors will pop up in console, but never mind them) and import V4. You might still be left with a couple of errors and warnings. Your best shot is to copy the text of those errors and google how to fix them.

Comment: But other than that this question does not belong to stackoverflow. Try unity forums, you might have some more luck there.